# Why am I getting 'Unable to find the wrapper https' error with file_get_contents on Apache, despite openssl config in php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, https, openssl, file-get-contents

I get an error: "Unable to find the wrapper https" when i execute file_get_contents via apache.
I have already configured extension=openssl in php.ini.
i try to dump the wrappers by using

```
echo var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());
```

and the result shows

[image: screenshot from apache].

It seems that the https wrapper is indeed missing.

but file_get_contents works well under php interactive shell and stream_get_wrappers shows wrapper has been loaded as

[image: screenshot from php interactive shell]

what could be the reason for those different behaviours between apache and php shell?
many thanks in advance for any hints

Environment: Apache 2.4.57 Win64 + PHP 8.2 (8.2.6) VS16 x64 Thread Safe

---

I solve this problem by installing another Apache version. the php.ini and httpd.conf are the same.
thank you all in particular @hakre for friendly support

Comment: Each environment (shell and web) has different PHP configuration files, so they can certainly have different behaviour and settings.

Comment: thanks, where can i locate the configuration file used by shell?
I think shell and apache(web) use the same configuration file, namely php.ini. 
if i comment and uncomment the extension like (extension=mysqli) it does have an effect on both the php execution in shell and on apache.

Comment: If you run phpinfo() it should tell you

Answer (score 0):

> what could be the reason for those different behaviours between apache and php shell?

This can be answerwered straight forward: Both have a different PHP configuration.

Your PHP shell has the https wrapper enabled, your Apache PHP has it disabled.

This is often easy to overlook, especially when getting started, as we think this is all PHP so assume this must be the same.

But the truth is, that PHP has many different so called *Server Application Programming Interfaces* (SAPI), and they all come with their own configuration.

Compare with the PHP Manual: [`php_sapi_name()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)

---

In the shell, PHP is commonly of the Command Line Interface (CLI) SAPI.

In the webserver, like Apache, it depends, it can be Common Gateway Interface (CGI), an Apache Module or the Fast CGI (FCGI) process manager (FPM).

> **A potential gotcha**
>
> The defined SAPI may not be obvious, because for example instead of `apache` it may be defined as `apache2handler`. *([ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php))*

---

### Consequences

[enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22011819/enlace) then asked about two specific PHP SAPI configurations in comments:

> 1. Where can I find the php configuration file for the shell?

For the shell, execute `php -i`, the output contains the location of the PHP ini file(s) at the beginning (pipe to `more` as it contains a lot of info).

> 2. How can I configure the php.ini (for apache) correctly. I did enable `extension=openssl` but it doesnt work.

For the apache webserver, double check you edited the correct ini file, use [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to display ini locations and settings as default/effective.

Some SAPIs (like some in Apache) allow you to configure PHP settings within the Server configuration itself as well. Consult the part about configuration in the PHP manual for more details. The section is called [Runtime Configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.php).

Also identify the SAPI, so you have a better understanding what the runtime is and how you have configured it.

Comment: first up thanks for the explanation. 
1. where can i find the php configuration file for the shell?
2. how can i configure the php.ini (for apache) correctly. i did enable extension=openssl but it doesnt work

Comment: @enlace: Thanks to your comment, I edited further clarifications into the answer.

Comment: so the phpinof() shows
>>Loaded Configuration File  ->  C:\workspace\php\php.ini
>>Configuration File (php.ini) Path -> no value
>>Scan this dir for additional .ini files -> (none)
it does read the php.ini i configured (PHPIniDir "C:/workspace/php") and the module like mysqli works well. (commenting and uncommenting extension=mysqli  in C:/workspace/php/php.ini do have effect.) only modification on extension=openssl seems not working. no clue where is the problem...

Comment: @enlace: Sorry, was away from keyboard, now reading your message. This looks that there is a single configuration file (`C:\workspace\php\php.ini`), this should make it straight forward in your case. Now about the extension. `extension=openssl` looks correct to me (in older php versions on windows that was `extension=openssl.dll` but IIRC this predates PHP 5.6 so just FYI about the filename of the extension on Microsoft Windows (Dynamic Link Library - DLL). There is also one setting called `extension_dir`, try to figure out the extension file is therein. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Also if an extension can not be loaded, you may find messages on the diagnostic channel. Apropos: As extensions are loaded when PHP starts, when you change the configuration for extensions, you need to restart/reload PHP, E.g. restart the Apache Webserver after a php.ini configuration change, then compare `phpinfo()` output again.